# How Insert DateTime Vales into Mysql Databse …Only End User gives Date

Tags: mysql

I am new developer in .net,I Have requirement..like this ,when user pick date from date picker not time only date he/she pick up,then click insert that time ,i want insert that date and time is into Column exist with name "EnterdDate" data type is "DATETIME". by default 00:00:00 is stored in the Time format I don't want to be stroed that values I want store The at the Time insertion MySql Server Time. 
**ex:user 12/03/2013 ->insert->click presently assume server time is 13:00:00** 
**i want insert This Date value --> 2013-03-12 13:00:00 ok for me.** 
**after 10 min I want insert the another record at time i want 2013-03-12 13:10:00
like server time in place of default time i am needed**
****i don't need the DateAndTime like is :2013-03-12 00:00:00 not Ok for me.***
please give best answer the above question.**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ADDTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) to add the [`CURTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) to the given date literal:

```
INSERT INTO my_table
  (EnteredDate)
VALUES
  (ADDTIME(CAST('2013-03-12' AS DATETIME), CURTIME())
```

One needs to `CAST()` the literal to a `DATETIME` value because `ADDTIME()` does not work with `DATE` types.